# requiring sign in upon url access

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, redirect

Ok, so I have been extremely so confused on how to solve that. 
I have a main page called **'index.html'**. It has a button that says **"create account"** that allows you to make an account, and another button that links to sign in page if you already have an account.

After you make an account when you **sign in** it will take you to a page called **'browse.html'** where you can see all the movies you can watch.

I just can't figure out how to redirect people that try to access **'browse.html'** from the URL to the sign in page. So like say you don't want to make an account, you could just type in the URL for the **'browse'** page and not have to create an account. I tried below code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=(my sign in page)">
```

in the header of **'Browse'** page, but that creates a loop that will never allow people to see the **'browse'** page movie list. 
I'm not good at explaining this, but I hope you can understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: What is your code server side? Why don't you use PHP to check the user state and redirect if needed with `header('Location: ')`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the php SESSIONS for that
first set the session variables in login and redirect to the browse page then check on browse page that if session has that variables then they can view the page else redirect to login page

for more info on sessions
go to http://ww.php.net and search for sessions